# No top-level getter <className> declared

Tags: dart, atom-editor, flutter

I am expanding on the flutter_gallery example.

I try to create new Gallery Item

```
new GalleryItem(
  title: 'Journal',
  subtitle: 'Example app coding',
  category: 'Apps',
  routeName: JournalDemo.routeName,
  buildRoute: (BuildContext context) => new JournalDemo()
),
```

and I imported `import '../journal/journal_all.dart';`

Inside I have `export 'journal_demo.dart';`

`JournalDemo` class is the same class as `ListDemo`, I only changed the class name and state name:

```
class JournalDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  JournalDemo({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = '/journal';

  @override
  JournalDemoState createState() => new JournalDemoState();
} 

class JournalDemoState extends State<JournalDemo> {
 .......
```

This is the exception I get

`I/flutter : ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter : The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building GalleryApp(dirty; state:
I/flutter : GalleryAppState(48280642)):
I/flutter : No top-level getter 'JournalDemo' declared.
I/flutter : NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'JournalDemo'
I/flutter : Receiver: top-level
I/flutter : Arguments: [...]
I/flutter : When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter : #0      NoSuchMethodError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:184)
I/flutter : #1      kAllGalleryItems (/Users/matej/IdeaProjects/flutter/journal/lib/gallery/item.dart:51)
I/flutter : #2      kAllGalleryItems (/Users/matej/IdeaProjects/flutter/journal/lib/gallery/item.dart:45)`

What should I change?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, don't hesitate to reach us (the Flutter developers) by emailing flutter-dev@googlegroups.com or joining our Gitter: https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter That might be a quicker way to get help.

Comment: What does the analyzer say? (`flutter analyze` in the app directory)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this locally making the changes you describe? Happy to work with you in https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter to debug further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you have either a missing import or a parse error in your code.  I would recommend checking with `flutter analyze` as one of the posters above suggests.

`No top-level getter 'JournalDemo' declared` means that it cannot find the value `JournalDemo` in the global scope.  Either because it's not imported, or because there is a parse error before this error.